# play turn-based game against untrusted player through untrusted communication

Tags: cryptography, communication

I think this question is related to cryptography.
Say Player A and B want to play Rock Paper Scissor game through the Internet.
There is not a server that both play trust, and they do not trust each other not to cheat.
I want to know how can they play a fair game with given scenario.
To be more precise, if neither player cheated, there should be a mechanism to let both player ensure that neither cheated.

Here is a naive solution that does not work:
First, both players send their choices to a server. After server receive both choices, it sends out the choices to both player.
The reason why this won't work is that the server might be an accomplice of player A. It will secretly send player B's choice before receiving player A's choice. Then player A can make a choice that wins player B. Throughout this process, Player B has not way of knowing whether player A cheated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a secure hashing function and random number generators to make players commit to their move before revealing it.

Something like this:

- Each player generates a random string, and sends it to the other player.
- Each player generates a second random string, and keeps it secret (temporarily).
- Each player chooses their move, and generates a signature for it, using the hashing function, and concatenating the two random strings to create a secret. Perhaps `HMAC_SHA512( my_string + other_string, move )` in pseudo-code, where first param is the MAC's *secret*, and by `+` I mean *string concatenation*. Equally `HMAC_SHA512( my_string, other_string + move )` works.
- Players publish their signatures to each other. At this stage, they have made a public commitment to make a move with a matching signature.
- Players then reveal their moves and second secret strings to each other, allowing the signatures to be verified.

This relies on the fact that if would be very hard to find a hash collision (two secrets which when combined with the other players "salt" and the move that would create the same signature). Technically, the hash function needs to have [collision resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) and [second preimage resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) to work well in this scenario - the former often implies the latter, and most HMAC functions available in a modern crypto library have these properties, at least from a practical standpoint of no known attacks better than brute-force. Once committed to a move signed with HMAC-SHA512 using a combined secret (combining the secret with data from the other player means you must look during the game, not search in advance for a collision), the players would find it impossible to declare anything other than the original signed move without being noticed.

It is also important that the generated random strings cannot be guessed, or all possibilities tried. They should be long (say 32+ bytes) and generated using a secure random number generator. If a player can simply try all the possible random strings, they could figure out what was being signed and respond with the correct counter-move.

Note that this method does not rely on a server. The server, or network, *could* create a man-in-the-middle attack here (by discarding one or both players' communication, and replacing with its own - it would not necessarily control the game result, but might mean the players were not really playing each other, but the server), so it is better if the communication is done securely peer-to-peer. If peer-to-peer is costly, then the only thing that has to be sent this way is the signature - if any component in-between the players then tries to change anything it would show up as the signatures not matching to published values.

Comment: The idea is sound; the quality you reference is the [second preimage resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) of the chosen hash function. But I think you have two steps reversed. The users should publish their signatures without the secrets first, only revealing the secret after the other user's encrypted move has been received.

Comment: @PatrickM: Thank you, yes I got the text on the last two bullet points confused, and hopefully now it is correct.

Comment: Second pre-image resistance is not enough for secure commitments, you need collision resistance since the attacker can influence both messages and not just one of them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I have added that, though I think it is less of an issue if the secret is unknown for a MAC, it is hard to make a general statement about such a protocol without the stronger restriction.